# Modifying volume of a specific channel in HTML5 audio

Tags: html5-audio

I have several MP3 files, each with two channels of audio. I need to play them in the browser, but give a volume control for each channel. I also need to support IE back to IE9, so it seems the Web Audio API is out of the question. Is this possible with HTML5 audio? I looked at several plugins but none met my needs.

Comment: AFAIK this is only possible with the Web Audio API (which you can't use in any IE version, so this one is already ruled out) or Flash. The only suggestion I can give you is splitting the channels to two separate MP3 files and then using two  audioElements and just set the `.volume` on them. Audio elements don't support panning.

Comment: And I'm sure I can't do that on the client, right? That would have to be done on the server?

Comment: Or on the computer you are using. I mean, split the channels to separate files and then upload them to your server, or are you using any kind of dynamic files?

Comment: They're not dynamic files, but we're auditing certain audio files so I'm not sure I can alter the original file. I was hoping to simply handle this on the client side, but I can possibly create two dynamic files on the server and stream both of them.

Comment: That's what I was aiming for. Use a program like audacity to split the audio in two separate files, and stream them to the client. I remember something like grouping audio elements to start and stop them at exactly the same time

Answer (score 2):

To format it in an answer:

It is not yet possible with html5 audio. Maybe Flash, but another trick is to split the channels in two separate files (so the server streams two files instead of one). I was thinking about a [mediaGroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_mediagroup.asp) solution, but my browser (Chrome dev) doesn't recoginize it (and I can hardly find *any* documentation about it).

Also is this about just choosing which channel (or a mix between them) is played to the user or do you also want to playback the left channel for instance to the left speaker only?

I recommend you to use event listeners for synchronously playing and pause'ing the audio. This way you don't need to save toggle states etc etc, it just keeps the code clean, simple and it works.

```
function play() {
    p1.play();
    p2.play();
}
function pause() {
    p1.pause();
    p2.pause();
}
p1.onplay = play();
p2.onplay = play();
p1.onpause = pause();
p2.onpause = pause();
```

This just makes sure that whenever one of the two players start or stop, they both start/stop.

I have put up a simple [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/PLXUp/) which is not yet complete, and the audio files are not the same length nor do they contain the same sound. It should give a good base to start from and contains a way of doing this. As I have no idea of your Javascript skills, there are no comments in the code, but feel free to ask an explanation for any of them.